# String Replace after the right most character

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, substring

Here is my character

```
/public/proj/index.php/home
/public/proj/index.php/test
/public/proj/home
/public/proj/test
```

I just need to replace the character after the right most '/' to login. So that it will be

```
/public/proj/index.php/login
/public/proj/index.php/login
/public/proj/login
/public/proj/login
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
$str = "/public/proj/index.php/home";
$vals = explode('/', $str);
$vals[count($vals)-1] = 'login';
$str = implode('/', $vals);
var_dump($str);
```

Comment: Nice trick with exploding the string and then subtract 1 from the count! Very cool idea

Comment: @Bizz I would accept sgt's answer! It's the simpler answer and works great! So he deserves it!

Comment: Thanks, Did the same !! Should be grateful to recommend others answers !!

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
$str = "/public/proj/home";
echo $str = substr_replace($str, "login", -1*(strlen(basename($str))), strlen(basename($str)));
```

Output:

```
/public/proj/login
```

Comment: what about `/public/project/home/home`?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Thanks for the hint! Didn't thought of that! (Then sgt answer is the better one :D)

Comment: Thanks, i will look after the remaining ,, Thanks

Comment: @Bizz accept sgt's answer! His one is the better one!

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst updated my answer now that your example works too! But a little bit more complicated then sgt's answer! So his answer is the better one!